# Probability of an employee retiring in the next 5 years given 1-year probabilities.

Tags: probability

I have a list of probabilities for retirement **in the next year** for a set of ages based on my company's data.

```
55  0.02296
56  0.03348
57  0.04777
58  0.06636
59  0.08931
60  0.11592
61  0.14467
62  0.17342
63  0.20001
64  0.22282
65  0.24107
66  0.25474
67  0.26434
68  0.27060
69  0.27426
70  0.27599
71  0.27633
72  0.27567
73  0.27432
74  0.27249
75  0.27035
76  0.26801
77  0.26553
78  0.26299
79  0.26040
80  0.25780
```

I know the current age of each employee so I can get the 1-year retirement probability. Using these probabilities, how can I get the probability that they retire any time in the next 5 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P_n$ be the probability that a person of age $n$ retires in the next year.

The probability that they retire within a year from now is $P_n$, which you're given.

The probability that they retire between $1$ and $2$ years from now is $(1-P_n)P_{n+1}$. (They didn't retire the first year, but did the second.)

The probability that they retire between $2$ and $3$ years from now is $(1-P_n)(1-P_{n+1})P_{n+2}$. (They didn't retire the first or second years, but did the third.)

And so forth for the next two years.

Then add them up!

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to work with the complement, the probability that they won't retire within $5$ years.

To compute this, create a new column $q_n=1-p_n$, the probability that an employee of age $n$ does not retire in the next year.  Then the probability that this employee (aged $n$) does not retire in the next $5$ years is given by:  $$Q_n=q_n\times q_{n+1}\times q_{n+2}\times q_{n+3}\times q_{n+4}$$

The answer you want is then $$P_n=1-Q_n$$